# AlertDialog. Spinner. Как установить размер выпадающей ячейки?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-linearlayout

Вставил `Spinner` в `AlertDialog`, но ячейки липнут в кучу.

[image: Сабж]

Перебрал массу настроек `Spinner`, но нужной не нашёл.

Layout спиннера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerFrom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_compare_arrows_black_48dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerTo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAmount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        tools:text="Введите сумму" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Буду благодарен помощи.

UPD. Добавляю код переопределения метода.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currenciesArray) {
            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                convertView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 12); // тут значение будет в пикселях
                return convertView;
            }
        };
```

Stacktrace:

```
04-26 13:41:57.349 22830-22830/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                             Process: com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter, PID: 22830
                                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.measureHeightOfChildrenCompat(ListViewCompat.java:311)
                                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1288)
                                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:641)
                                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.show(AppCompatSpinner.java:782)
                                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick(AppCompatSpinner.java:432)
                                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: для кастомного вида айтема у спиннера установите маржины для корневого контейнера этого айтема.

Comment: @pavlofff все попытки поменять маржины и вообще любые настройки меняют только первый элемент, который отображается в спиннере. Когда открываешь выпадающее меню, всё та же унылая куча.

Comment: Изменять нужно не атрибуты самого спиннера, а разметку айтема. У вас используется системная `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` - подберите другую системную разметку, которая больше вам подходит или создайте свою на основе системной с необходимыми маржинами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно посмотреть в сторону настроек самих ячеек :)

Вы определенно уже используете в `Spinner` какой-то `SpinnerAdapter` например `ArrayAdapter`, которому Вы передаёте разметку ячеек. В этой разметке добавьте ячейкам `padding`, например:

```
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
```

Но можно переопределить у `SpinnerAdapter` метод `getDropDownView`, если хотите, чтобы `padding`, существовал только в выпадающем списке, например:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 12); // тут значение будет в пикселях
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Пока не получилось. При попытке переопределения метода вылетает NPE. Прикрепил стектрейс.

Comment: Ну определенно с таким переопределением будет выпадать NPE :) дополнил код

Comment: Да, после правок всё заработало. Спасибо.